# ¿Existe alguna manera de reducir el tamaño base minimo de un objeto std::string?

Tags: c++, string

Estaba probando las funciones miembro de la clase **std::string** especialmente **size()**, **capacity()** y **shrink_to_fit()** y me di cuenta de que en mi implementación de std::string el tamaño base minimo de un objeto string es siempre 15 no importa si fue inicializado vacio y que además no se puede reducir su tamaño a menor de 15 con el método shrink_to_fit(); esto indica que en un caso hipotetico si creara 100 objetos string cada uno conteniendo una cadena con un tamaño igual o menor a 10 chars se asignaria memoria suficiente para contener cada cadena, pero que además se reservarian mas de 500 direcciones de memoria que no serian usadas, eso seria un manejo de memoria muy ineficiente.

¿Existe alguna manera de reducir el tamaño base minimo de un string a menor de 15 si no se esta usando su capacidad completa? Y de no haber alguna manera de hacerlo ¿Cuál es la mejor solución que podría implementarse para un caso como el que plantee?

Uso Ubuntu 18.04 y mi compilador es el GCC 7.5.0.

Comment: En equipos PC, **nunca jamas** vas a poder reservar 1 solo byte. Por debajo, la memoria se gestiona en bloques. Por mucho que tu pidas 1 byte, en realidad y a nivel físico, el sistema *cogerá* un bloque y te devolverá la primera dirección del mismo, **desperdiciando el resto**.

Answer (score 4):

> eso seria un manejo de memoria muy ineficiente.

Pues depende.

Para empezar tienes que tener en cuenta que estás trabajando con memoria dinámica y esta memoria tiene sus peculiaridades.

**Fragmentación de la memoria**

Si mezclas el uso de objetos que hacen reservas muy pequeñas junto con otros que hacen uso de bloques de memoria más grandes, acabarás llenando la memoria dinámica de huecos demasiado pequeños para ser usados. El resultado sería algo así como un queso gruyere. El problema que podrías encontrar en este supuesto es que tu programa no sería capaz de reservar más memoria pese a tener mucha memoria disponible (pero en fragmentos muy pequeños y dispersos).

**Tiempos de ejecución**

La reserva de memoria dinámica es uno de los procesos más lentos que te puedes echar a la cara. Hacer reservas de unos pocos bytes suele consumir el mismo tiempo que una reserva de cientos de megas.

Hacer reservas muy pequeñas obligaría, en la mayoría de las situaciones, a tener que hacer reservas más grandes en el momento de almacenar una cadena en el objeto... Cuando esto pasa pagas un peaje doble:

- Reserva inicial minúscula
- Reserva de mayor tamaño para guardar la cadena

Establecer un tamaño mínimo razonable tiene su sentido ya que evitas, en el caso de almacenar cadenas de pequeño tamaño, tener que esperar a que se haga una nueva reserva de memoria solo para almacenar tu cadena.

El tamaño mínimo de 15 bytes te permite almacenar en ese objeto prácticamente cualquier palabra suelta que puedas escribir... algo que suele ser bastante común.

Si ya llegas al extremo de almacenar frases... lo siento pero la memoria inicial será insuficiente.

**Sistemas modernos**

Esta reserva inicial de 15 bytes es lo suficientemente pequeña como para que el desperdicio de memoria tampoco sea alarmante.

Un equipo pequeño, pongamos algo tipo una raspberry, puede tener en torno a 256MB de memoria RAM, eso te daría para almacenar 17 millones de objetos de tipo string en su formato básico ... quizás hace 20 años este consumo de 15 bytes podría ser algo intolerable, pero hoy en día dudo que te encuentres con sistemas mínimamente modernos en los que ese *despilfarro* sea inasumible

**Tu problema**

Para evitar ese despilfarro y enfrentarte a otros problemas tendrás que crear tu propia clase `string`. También puedes bajar el nivel y usar punteros a `char`, cada opción tiene sus retos y son, cada una en su medida, opciones normalmente desaconsejadas

Answer (score -2):

Si quieres trabajar con string. Te recomiendo usar C. Es mas complejo al concatenar cadena pero util cuando se trata de almacenamiento de cadena:

```
     char* a="hola mundo";//Esto es un puntero que apunta a la dirección estactica de la cadena, por ser un puntero que apunta a la cadena se puede hace esto:
     a="Not Hello World";//La cadena será almacenada en la memoria y el puntero "a" ahora apunta a esa memoria.
```

O puedes usar

```
    char a[15];
    strpy(a,"hola mundo");
```

Esto te dará espació suficiente para 15 carácteres incluyendo \0